# Representation Theory: homomorphism of representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am working on the following lemma.

---

**Lemma**
Let $G$ be a finite group, $V,W$ vector spaces over a field $k$. Let $\rho_1 :G\rightarrow GL(W)$ and $\rho_2:G\rightarrow GL(\oplus_{h\in G} V)$ be representation, in particular $\rho_2$ is a regular representation. Then we have an isomorphism

$\Phi:\text{Hom}(W,V)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_G(W,\oplus_{h\in G} V),\\ \phi\mapsto\Phi(\phi):W\rightarrow \oplus_{h\in G} V, \ w\mapsto\Phi(\phi)(w):=(\phi(\rho(h^{-1})w))_{h\in G}$

---

I am really confused about the use of the notation. The first thing to prove is the well-definiteness of the map, that means that we have to show that $\Phi(\phi)$ is in fact a homomorphism of representation, i.e. that it is linear and that it satisfies the compatibility condition. Linearity seams pretty clear but for the second part is not that proper.

My first question is about the following two type of notations which I suspect are the problem here. Introducing the regular representation we saw that we can write the action of the group on the direct sum $\oplus k$ as follows: $ g\in G\mapsto (h\mapsto gh)\in GL(\oplus k)$ stating that this is an abuse of notation and an homomorphism. Just as a second part we state that in a proper notation this would be: $g\mapsto ((x_h)_{h\in G}\mapsto(x_{g^{-1}}h)_{h\in G})$. I have some difficult by seeing what is the link between the two type of writing this and I don't get the reason we want to use a more improper one (the first).

Returning to the proof of the lemma:

As stated we have two representations, i.e. two different homomorphisms. But for the proof in my notes we do not care about we just let $G$ act on $(\phi(\rho(h^{-1})w))_{h\in G}$ and get $(\phi(\rho((g^{-1}h)^{-1})w))_{h\in G}$ and concluding noting that this is the image of $\rho(g)w$, as required.

Why we do not distinguish between $\rho_1,\rho_2$?

Thanks for any help

Comment: That's some crappy notation in there. The $\rho_2$ in the lemma is not "a regular representation"; it is just constructed similarly to that (probably in an attempt to define induced representations without tensor products). What source are you reading? I'd advise switching to a different one.

Comment: That's a nice advice :D but I cannot. This comes from my lecture notes

Comment: There is still the option of reading other lecture notes... You probably won't miss much. Any set of notes that involves group algebras should clear up your confusion. The group algebra $kG$ is defined to be the free $k$-vector space with basis $G$ (so its elements are formal $k$-linear combinations of elements of $G$, in the same way as the elements of the polynomial ring $k\left[x\right]$ are formal $k$-linear combinations of the symbols $1$, $x$, $x^2$, $\ldots$), and it becomes a representation of $G$ by the rule that $g \in G$ sends $h \in G \subseteq kG$ to $gh \in G \subseteq kG$.

Comment: Now, there is an isomorphism $kG \to \bigoplus_{h \in G} k$ of representations of $G$. (This isomorphism sends each $a \in G \subseteq kG$ to the family in $\bigoplus_{h \in G} k$ whose $a$-th entry is $1$ and whose other entries are all $0$.) Your source pretends that these two representations are the same and the isomorphism is the identity.